# Why can't I use method call inside "module" block for define_method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, activesupport-concern

I have a model class with attr_reader - `type_slugs` (returns an array of string) which I'd like to use to generate several methods.

For example:

```rb
module Orders
  module Extensions
    module Order
      module TypeCheckable
        extend ::ActiveSupport::Concern

        ::Orders::Config.type_slugs.each do |type|
          define_method("#{type}_order_type?") { order_type == type }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But it gives me `` NoMethodError: undefined method `type_slugs' for Orders::Config:Module ``

Same error happens if I use any model method like:

```rb
some_method_defined_in_model.each do |type|
  define_method("#{type}_order_type?") { order_type == type }
end
```

But it works just fine if I use a word array

```rb
%w(message product another).each do |type|
  define_method("#{type}_order_type?") { order_type == type }
end
```

Is it even possible to use `Orders::Config.type_slugs` in this case? If not, why so?

Comment: Do you include the module before the `type_slugs` definition in the source file?

Comment: How `Orders::Config` looks? How `type_slugs` is defined?

Comment: "I have a model class with attr_reader - `type_slugs`". 1) It appears that `::Orders::Config` is a `Module` and not a "model class". 2) is the attr_reader added to the eigenclass? If not this is an instance method (which seems to be the actual issue), e.g. `ModelClass.new.method_name_that_exists`. 3) `Module`s don't have instances, new quandary. You are going to need to post more code before we can help.

Comment: When using [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), you should also use the `included` and/or `class_methods` blocks to define your code, depending on where you want it to be evaluated (instance vs. class/module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you provided, it follows that the module `Orders::Config` does not have `type_slugs` method

If you want your code works, you need define it, something like this:

```rb
module Orders
  module Config
    def self.type_slugs
      %w[message product another]
    end
  end
end
```

Or if that list doesn't change dynamically:

```rb
module Orders
  module Config
    TYPE_SLUGS = %w[message product another].freeze
  end
end
```

In that case change `::Orders::Config.type_slugs` to `::Orders::Config::TYPE_SLUGS`

When use [Rails concerns](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), you should use `included` for instance methods

```rb
module Orders
  module Extensions
    module Order
      module TypeCheckable
        extend ::ActiveSupport::Concern

        included do
          ::Orders::Config::TYPE_SLUGS.each do |type|
            define_method("#{type}_order_type?") { order_type == type }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After that you can use it in your models

```rb
class SuperOrder < ApplicationRecord
  include Orders::Extensions::Order::TypeCheckable
end

class BestOrder < ApplicationRecord
  include Orders::Extensions::Order::TypeCheckable
end
```

And call methods like this

```rb
SuperOrder.new.product_order_type? # compare super order type with "product"
BestOrder.new.message_order_type? # compare best order type with "message"
```